# User is not allowed to impersonate anonymous (state=08S01,code=0) org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

I am getting the below error when I try to start Hive using hiverserver2.

```
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
18/10/25 09:45:38 [main]: WARN jdbc.HiveConnection: Failed to connect to localhost:10000
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: Failed to open new session: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): User: deco is not allowed to impersonate anonymous (state=08S01,code=0)
```

The user name I am using is **deco**.

I have also added the below entry in core-site.xml file:

```
<property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.deco.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.deco.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
</property>
```

I am still unable to connect using beeline. I used the following commands:

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
```

and

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/beeline -n $(whoami) -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
```

I even took a backup of the metastore_db folder and reinitiated with the below command:

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/schematool -dbType derby -initSchema
```

I even started hiveserver2 on 10001 port and connected beeline to 10001 and still got the same error

All the above prove futile.

Help I am dying

Answer (score 11):

I ever got this error

> User * is not allowed to impersonate anonymous

That's because by default hive tries to execute operations as the calling user, I add below lines to hive config file conf/hive-site.xml, to ask hive to execute operations as the hiveserver2 process user, then get rid of this error:

```
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
    <value>false</value>
    <description>
      Setting this property to true will have HiveServer2 execute
      Hive operations as the user making the calls to it.
    </description>
  </property>
```

[Here is the document](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Setting+Up+HiveServer2#SettingUpHiveServer2-Impersonation):

> Impersonation
>
> By default HiveServer2 performs the query processing as
>   the user who submitted the query. But if the following parameter is
>   set to false, the query will run as the user that the hiveserver2
>   process runs as.
>
> hive.server2.enable.doAs – Impersonate the connected user, default
>   true.